# Conditions for a minimization mapping to be a contraction

Tags: real-analysis, random-variables, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points, contraction-operator

Let $\Omega$ be a set of elements $\omega\in\Omega$ and let $A(\omega)$ be a random variable. Consider the function
$$
K(\omega,A(\omega),P)
$$
where $P>0$. Assume that $K$ is strictly positive, and nondecreasing and continuously differentiable in $P$.

Consider the mapping $T(P)$ defined as
$$
T(P) = K(\omega_P,A(\omega_P),P)
$$
where $\omega_P=\arg\min_\omega E[K(\omega,A(\omega),P)]$.

I am looking for a way to show that $T$ has a (unique?) fixed point $P^*=T(P^*)$ (note that $P^*$ will be a random variable in general). To do so, my plan is to show that $T$ is a contraction: there is an $0\leq r<1$ such that, for any $P$ and $P'$, we have
$$
||T(P)-T(P')||\leq r ||P-P'||.
$$

I'm happy to assume additional restrictions on $K$ and $A$ to get to that result if needed. Any help would be much appreciated!

#### What I've tried so far

I haven't been able to make much progress. It seems that using the norm $||x||=E[|x|]$ might be useful. For instance, we can write
\begin{align}
||T(P)-T(P')|| &= E\left[\left|K(\omega_P,A(\omega_P),P)-K(\omega_{P'},A(\omega_{P'}),P')\right|\right]
\end{align}
If we make the (restrictive) assumption that $K(\omega_P,A(\omega_P),P)\geq K(\omega_{P'},A(\omega_{P'}),P')$ we can write
$$
||T(P)-T(P')|| = \min_\omega E\left[K(\omega,A(\omega),P)\right]-\min_\omega E\left[K(\omega,A(\omega),P')\right]$$
But I'm not sure how to make $E[|P-P'|]$ appear in there.

It might also be possible to use Tarski's fixed point theorem but I haven't made much progress on that front either.

Comment: Maybe google "Blackwell's Sufficient Conditions for a Contraction"

Comment: I thought of that but it's not clear how to show that the mapping is monotone.

Comment: What is the meaning of $\arg\min_{\omega} E[K(\omega, A(\omega), P)]$?  The expectation is with respect to the random outcome $\omega$ and so it looks like there is no $\omega$ left to minimize. For a given $P$, it looks like $K(\omega, A(\omega), P)$ is just a random variable, so $E[K(\omega, A(\omega), P)]$ is a number (not a function of $\omega$). I am assuming $\Omega$ is the sample space and $\omega$ a particular outcome.

Comment: @Michael $\omega$ is not random, it's the "choice variable". For each $\omega$, $A(\omega)$ is a random variable. Sorry If that was not clear.

Comment: Thanks.  Usually a random variable $X:\Omega \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is represented by either $X$ or $X(\omega)$ and they mean the same, so $E[X]$ and $E[X(\omega)]$ mean the same thing. Just like $P[X\leq 5]$ means the same as  $P[\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \leq 5\}]$. So your notation just happens to overlap with that standard notation.

Answer (score 1):

Use the envelope theorem on $T$ with respect to the parameter $p$, letting $P$ be the convex space of $p$'s, and $\mathcal{C}$ a smooth curve from $p'$ to $p$:
\begin{eqnarray}
|T(p)-T(p')| &=& \left| \int_{p'}^p \nabla_p K(w(z),A(z),z) d\mathcal{C} \right|\\
&\le& ||p-p'|| \sup_{z \in \mathcal{C}} \left|\left| \nabla_p K(w(z),A(z),z)\right|\right|\\
&\le& ||p-p'|| \sup_{z \in P} \left|\left| \nabla_p K(w(z),A(z),z)\right|\right|
\end{eqnarray}
And assume (or provide sufficient conditions) that 
$$
r = \sup_{z \in P} \left|\left| \nabla_p K(w(z),A(z),z)\right|\right| <1.
$$
Does that work? See Milgrom and Segal, "Envelope Theorems for Arbitrary Choice Sets."

Comment: That might just work! I'm not familiar with those envelope theorems but it looks promising. Will read that reference now. My worry is that $\omega$ and $A$ do not come from the maximization of $K$ itself but of $E[K]$. I'm not sure if we can use these theorems in that case.

Comment: I didn't really understand the expectation piece either. I didn't follow how the random variable $A(\omega)$ depending on the decision variable $\omega$ so I just skipped it in the answer. You could just extend what I wrote to include taking the sup over the support of the random variable, as long as it has compact support: $\sup_{z \in P, A \in \mathcal{A}}$.  On the other hand, the norm of the $\mathbb{E}$ operator is one, so you mean something like $\int_{A \in \mathcal{A}} f[A|z] K(w(z),A,z)dA$ where the density of $A$ depends on $z$, you can fit that in too.